# Excel, create variable criteria for countifs with input selector

Tags: excel

I have

```
=Countifs(A:A;"cr1";G:G;"4")
```

I want to make an input selector for `"4"` from a dropdown box showing all the options in row G.

I am not sharp at much and surely not excel, so I am not sure where to start - I am guessing I will need to have a variable input in `Countifs()` instead of 4 and create an input selector, selecting the variable? Or is that totally wrong?

I have no idea where to start. Any help is appreciated much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below formula-

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A;"cr1";G:G;H1)
```

Here `H1` is you input selector dropdown box.